# Oracle generate range between 2 columns of data

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day All,

I have a table structured as below

```
f_number    act_date    amount  range_start     range_end
-------------------------------------------------------------
T18564      20140702        10  700102180211    700102195210
T18564      20140702        10  700104371331    700104376330
T18564      20140702        20  700250037215    700250077214
T18564      20140702        30  600311039928    600311044927
```

How do I generate all the numbers in between ranges so that my data is displayed as,

```
f_number    act_date    amount  item_id
--------------------------------------------
T18564      20140702        10  700102180211    
                                ...
T18564      20140702        10  700102195210
T18564      20140702        10  700104371331
                                ...
T18564      20140702        10  700104376330
```

and so forth. I tried using,

```
select f_number, act_date, amount, to_number(range_start - 1) + level as item_id
  from table
connect by level <= (to_number(range_end) - to_number(range_start)) + 1
```

but it works OK for the first range then goes wrong after.

*to_number is used because the ranges are stored as varchar2

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in order to use `CONNECT BY` effectively, you need to identify each row uniquely. I don't see any kind of primary key or unique identifier in your data above (and are you storing numbers and dates in `VARCHAR2` columns? Bad idea). So you might try something like this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT 'T18564' AS f_number, '20140702' AS act_date
         , 10 AS amount, '700102180211' AS range_start
         , '700102195210' AS range_end
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18564', '20140702', 10, '700104371331', '700104376330'
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18564', '20140702', 20, '700250037215', '700250077214'
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'T18564', '20140702', 30, '600311039928', '600311044927'
      FROM dual
)
SELECT f_number, act_date, amount, range_start - 1 + LEVEL
  FROM (
    SELECT f_number, act_date, amount
         , TO_NUMBER(range_start) AS range_start
         , TO_NUMBER(range_end) AS range_end
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS rn
      FROM t1
) CONNECT BY range_start - 1 + LEVEL <= range_end
      AND PRIOR rn = rn
      AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that I'm using `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a unique row identifier. You could also use something like `SYS_GUID()` if you were inclined (the order should not matter in this case).

I ran the above in Oracle 10g and it returned the correct number of rows (in this case, 65000 -- the sum of range_end - range_start + 1).

Comment: Brilliant and thanks for the added value in response. I had 129 ranges to work with; Notepad++ made formatting them easy for this query.